# How to load locale dependent strings in android programmatically?

Tags: android

In Android it's possible to define i18n strings with:

```
values/strings.xml
values-de/strings.xml
```

And use them in xml like:
`android:text="@string/hello"`

The local specific string is automatically resolved.

But: how can I achieve the same programmatically? Load the string from the styles definition, automatically in the correct localisation?

Comment: I assume instead of `styles.xml` you mean `strings.xml`

Comment: Of course, thanks I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you retrieve the `String` using the `Context` it will return the locale dependent one.

```
context.getString(R.string.hello);
```

You can see more from the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...)).